# How to install Shumway in Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 26/Nightly for watching videos in Youtube?

Tags: firefox

I am desperately trying to install Shumway in Firefox 26/Nightly with Ubuntu 12.04 running, but it doesn't work with Youtube.

What I tried so far:

- purging every flash package and getting the plugin using the Shumway
  homepage.
- trying to combine Lightspark with Shumway plugin
- adding stuff to about:config as suggesting under Shumway HP /
  configuring the extension.

The "testsites" suggest and/or run by Shumway developers are working fine and I have this plugin up and running on another pc (works there with youtube). So, yeah, no idea what I could do.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Keep trying - I had disabled the Firefox plugin, but am experiencing a bug where - among other things the flashplugin-installer is in an unconfigured state.

Out of curiosity I enabled the Shumway plugin again and have live video in astonishingly high definition compared to flash, even in full screen.

It takes several seconds longer to load, but it's worth the wait. You also have the option to switch to flash by way of a right click of the mouse.